# How to include a meter in Manipulate that shows a value calculated from the manipulate dynamic variable?

Tags: manipulate, visualization

I'm trying to make a visualization of grid (representing magnetic states) and I want to include a meter that shows a variable calculated from the manipulate index (of the form `J1/J2 = (index)*0.1)` so that as you change the index next to the array plot you see the numerical value of `J1/J2`. Any idea how to do this?

Here's my code:

```
Manipulate[ ArrayPlot[MontesJ[[i, 1]],  ColorRules -> {1 -> White, -1 -> Black}], {i, 1, 20, 1}]
```

`Montes[[i,1]]` is a square grid.

Comment: For example : `Manipulate[Row[{i, ArrayPlot[MontesJ[[i, 1]], ColorRules -> {1 -> White, -1 -> Black}]}], {i, 1, 20, 1}]`

Comment: So this works to show the index next to the array plot but is there any way I can have it show "J1/J2 = i"

Comment: Yes, simply  : `Manipulate[Row[{"J1/J2 = ",i, ArrayPlot[ ...`